# Changing the php color tags in VSC

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, settings

How can I change the color of the opening and closing tags of php in VSC?

The theme I am using (Cobalt3) has them in white and I really want to change to something more standout.

[image]

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In VS code go to settings->command pallette (or press ctrl+shift+p)
2. In the search bar write: "Open Workspace Settings (json)"
3. It will open a json file which should be empty;
4. In that file copy paste the following and save

   "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "textMateRules": [
   {
   "name": "PHP Purple Tags",
   "scope": [
   "punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php",
   "punctuation.section.embedded.end.php"
   ],
   "settings": {
   "foreground": "#6600cc"
   }
   },
   ]
   }

Your php tag color should change. You can play with the color code to see what fits your need.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!